# Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Auto suggestion and error detection is not working

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Yesterday I have Updated my android studio, since then auto completion and error detection is not working.

Answer (score 2):

First close Android Studio.

On mac just go to ~/Library/Application Support/Google/

And delete all the AndroidStudio< version > folders, after this you will see the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting Android Studio settings. Close Android Studio, locate and delete this folder (copy to another location before deleting, so you can return to it if something goes wrong).

> C:\Users<Your User>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio< version >

This should reset your Android Studio settings to default. Now check if auto-complete and error detection works or not.

Comment: Not worked on MacOS